# Echarts xAxis dates overlapping and zooming echarts, forcing first date come without sequence/interval

Tags: vue.js, graph, charts, vuejs3, echarts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKCZU.png)

echart version used : 5.4.2
Vue 3 application.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zm4D.png)
The issue is regarding the xAxis labels, they are overlapping each other, the xAxis in my case of dates, I also have Zooms in my app, when we select some filters for example the 90-day chart the first date is forced to come in without interval definition.

I used hideOverlap: true, property but it is just hiding the overlapping not getting rid of first date foced to come.

I am expecting that the intervals/sequences should be 'Equal' neither overlapping nor forced label of first date, and the sequence and differences must be 'equivalent' to the filter provided.
Comment more information if required. Thanks